# Minimum spanning tree between a start location and a set of required nodes

Tags: algorithm, search, graph-theory, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to determine the optimal search case to compare to a search algorithm I have written.

I have a set of nodes marked "required" and a node marked "start", the rest are marked "optional".  I want to find the optimal number of nodes I would need to expand to discover all of the required nodes given that I my first expand is the "start" node.

- I believe what I am looking for is the minimum spanning tree, but pruned of all branches that do not end in a "required" node.  Is this the [Steiner tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem)?
- If my graph is unweighted, is the size of the Steiner tree and the
  Minimum Spanning Tree the same?
- What if anything can I say about the size of the tree?  i.e. something like (size of minimum spanning tree size = average shortest path * # required nodes...I don't think this is true, but it would be nice to be able to calculate an average based on connectedness or something).

A few notes:

1. This is not traveling sales problem because I don't need a path
   to exist between each required node, I just want to discover each
   required node.
2. My graph is undirected and unweighted (or equally weighted for that matter)
3. My graph has an average of about 100 required nodes, and possibly thousands of optional nodes

Comment: By definition if you run your algorithm, the optimal tree will be the one which minimizes the total weighted paths connecting the nodes. Therefore any subpath along the tree would, if erased (and the other paths left the same), would be the optimal path you would have to recreate to re-link the required elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a set of nodes marked "required" and a node marked "start", the
>   rest are marked "optional". I want to find the optimal number of nodes
>   I would need to expand to discover all of the required nodes given
>   that I my first expand is the "start" node.

If the cost of expanding a node can be arbitrary, then this is the node-weighted Steiner tree problem, which, under a plausible complexity-theoretic assumption, has no polynomial-time approximation algorithm with a ratio that's o(log n).

> I believe what I am looking for is the minimum spanning tree, but
>   pruned of all branches that do not end in a "required" node.

No, this is in general not optimal. For example, with the graph

```
       s
      /|\
     / | \
    *  |  *
   /   |   \
  /    |    \
 r1----*----r2,
```

one possible MST looks like `/|\` or `/\` when pruned, but the optimal solution looks like `_|_`.

> What if anything can I say about the size of the tree?

Theoretically speaking, you could get a lower bound by solving the dual of the LP relaxation of the integer program for Steiner tree (actually with a graph of a the size you're thinking about, it wouldn't surprise me if a solver could determine the optimal Steiner tree straight up).

Practically speaking, however, this is not how people evaluate search algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Would you suggest a better approach to evaluate the search algorithm?  What would be more practical?

Comment: If the instance is small enough that the whole tree can be expanded, then it's not very interesting. Optimization researchers typically push their algorithms as far as they can go and compare the time/space usage against previous attempts and naive baselines.